# Can a library version become unavailable in the next point release of Debian?

Tags: linux, debian, shared-libraries

On the website of Debian, it's written about [point releases](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianReleases/PointReleases):

> They usually incorporate the security fixes released until the time of
>   the update and fixes for grave bugs in the current release.

If I correctly understand, that means only minor updates can occur in the packages of the current stable version, right?

In other words, I want to know if a binary who depends of a library in a specific version (`libmicrohttpd.so.12` for instance) will stay compatible in the next point releases of Debian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but it is very seldom.

In general you are right, the point releases should not change existing API and ABI.

But there could be problems on doing that: security changes would require a lot of work, and upstream will do only for the new version. In such cases the version will be dump. But this is very seldom: it would need a security bug which effect the fundamental design of a library (not just some coding error).

In any case the old version will remain on archives, and you can keep it (so that it would not be automatically removed), so that you can still use, hopefully with relevant safe guard.